# Ignore dependency jars on dist task

Tags: playframework, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I have a Play 2.3.x app that consists of some subprojects, and I use `dist` to generate a zip package of the full application.

The problem is that this package is too big, because it includes every dependency needed for the app to run (ex: scala, play libs, db driver(s), etc), and takes a lot of time to upload to the server.

I was wondering: it is possible to tell `dist` task to ignore some of those jars and don't include them in the generated zip file? The idea was to have those dependencies on the server and a custom start script to add all those deps to the classpath, and only deploy a smaller zip with only my code/assets jars.

Is this possible?

Comment: There is already a [feature request](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/issues/365) for this. However this is a really big and complicated thing on what to package and what not. As an initial step I recommend something like proguard to reduce your number of class files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dist` task comes from [sbt-native-packager](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager). Version 0.7.4 is used in the Play 2.3 lineage.

If you run `sbt show universal:mappings` you will get output of all the currently included things in your project. So by modifying the `mappings` key you can start to (carefully) filter away whatever you desire.

EDIT: As Muki points out in the comments, here is a [direct link](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/universal.html#filter-remove-mappings) to the relevant documentation.

Comment: Can you show a small example (ex: include only `junit.junit-4.10.jar` in the generated package)?

Comment: Sure, a bit rushed but one way to do it: https://github.com/Lykathia/ignore-sbt-dependencies

Comment: There is some [more documentation here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/universal.html#customize). Mappings are pretty simple: source:File -> dest:String tuples. You can filter on them as you want. E.g. `mappings in Universal := (mappings in Universal).value.filter { case (source, dest) => dest contains "lib/" }`